# WPF: ContentPresenter within DataTemplate shows incorrect DataTemplate content

Tags: wpf, data-binding, telerik, datatemplate, contentpresenter

Given the following (simplified) class...

```
class SearchResultsViewModel
{

    public IList Results { get; }

    public SearchCriteria Criteria { get; }

}
```

And the following (also simplified) WPF DataTemplate's...

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:SearchCriteria}">
    <StackPanel>
        <!-- Various controls used to display/edit  the SearchCriteria class properties-->
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:SearchResultsViewModel}">
    <telerik:RadDocking>

        <telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>
            <telerik:RadSplitContainer>
                <telerik:RadPaneGroup>
                    <telerik:RadDocumentPane Visibility="Collapsed"
                                             CanUserClose="False">
                        <telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Results}" />
                    </telerik:RadDocumentPane>
                </telerik:RadPaneGroup>
            </telerik:RadSplitContainer>
        </telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>

        <telerik:RadSplitContainer InitialPosition="DockedLeft">
            <telerik:RadPaneGroup IsContentPreserved="True">
                <telerik:RadPane CanUserClose="False"
                                 CanFloat="False"
                                 DataContext="{Binding Path=Criteria}"
                                 Header="Search Criteria"
                                 IsPinned="False">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
                </telerik:RadPane>
            </telerik:RadPaneGroup>
        </telerik:RadSplitContainer>

    </telerik:RadDocking>
</DataTemplate>
```

When I display the SearchResultsViewModel (using a ContentPresenter), I see - as expected - a list of the results along with a tab on the left of the page with the header "Search Criteria"; however when I then click on the tab to open the associated panel and view the properties of the "SearchCriteria" class I see a repeat of the whole "SearchResultsViewModel" DataTemplate instead of just the properties of the "SearchCriteria" using its own DataTemplate. This then repeats recursively so each time I click on the tab it opens yet another copy.

[image: Tab is closed, you see the column headers]

[image: Tab is expanded, you can see the full repetition]

I have also tried setting "Content={Binding Path=Criteria}" on the "ContentPresenter" instead of setting the "DataContext={Binding Path=Criteria}" on the "RadPane" but this makes no difference.

I use the DataTemplate for the "SearchCriteria" elsewhere within the application and it is called upon based upon the DataType being shown rather than any specific reference to the specific template so I do not want to have to give the template an "x:Key" and then reference it specifically here either but then I do not expect to have to do this as it works elsewhere.

What am I doinng wrong to make the ContentPresenter within the second DataTemplate show the "SearchCriteriaViewModel" DataTemplate instead of the "SearchCriteria" DataTemplate?

Comment: How or when do you set `Criteria`, on construction of `SearchResultsViewModel`?

Comment: If `SearchResultsViewModel` doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or the `PropertyChanged` event is not raised when `Criteria` is set the binding won't update and the `ContentPresenter` remains empty. Also make sure that the `DataTemplate` for a `SearchCriteria` is defined within the scope of the `ContentPresenter`. You could try to move it to App.xaml.

Comment: @BionicCode makes a good point; where are your templates defined?

Comment: I am not familiar with this Rad control. But you could try to bind to the `RadDocking.DataContext` directly. Probably the `RadPane` handles `DataContext` differently. Because from your statement _"...view the properties of the `SearchCriteria` class I see a repeat of the whole `SearchResultsViewModel` DataTemplate instead..."_ it looks like the `DataContext` is not what you expect it to be. It's obviously a `SearchResultsViewModel`.

Comment: So modifying the binding to: `<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type RadDocking}}, Path=DataContext.Criteria}" />` should solve the problem.

Comment: Criteria is set against SearchResultsViewModel by property assignment before the SearchResultsViewModel is passed to the view. SearchResultsViewModel does support INotifyPropertyChange (including the Criteria property). Both of the templates shown are defined in the same ResourceDictionary and in the order shown.

Comment: Binding with FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadDocking} did not work either I am afraid and yes, the DataContext always seems to be the ...ViewModel and never the SearchCriteria.

Comment: Also what is `IsContentPreserved` exactly doing? Can you set it to `false`? Maybe it "freezes" the content of  `ContentPresenter`. From docs I can tell it should keep the state of the pane's content. But who knows. It looks like the control prevents the content itself to change (to simplify state persistence I guess). All the bindings are supposed to resolve. Maybe it boils down to `IsContentPreserved` as the authors may expected you to define the content of the panes inline.

Comment: But I don't know, so I would just try it. After setting this property to `false` I would try to add content explicitly by in-lining the controls.

Comment: IsContentPreserved has not made a difference; I originally added it in case the original binding was being lost in the recreation of the view each time it is made visible.

Comment: I have also tried copying in the content of the SearchCriteria template as you suggested and that is now erroring (Output Window) that it cannot find the properties to bind to even though I am setting DataContext={Binding Path=Criteria} on the StackPanel that contains the fields. If I remove the DataContext binding on the StackPanel and prefix the property names in the individual control bindings the same errors - cannot find property on SearchCriteriaViewModel.

Comment: This message surely doesn't lie. Can you verify that this property exits on this very type and that it is `public`? Are you referencing the right view model? Maybe you have a typo somewhere. Check it carefully although you might be sure everything is fine.

Comment: Just double checked; I can see the Criteria being set and the value being set is valid. I can also see the property being accessed via the getter and again the value being returned is correct. There are no binding errors in the Output Window indicating typing mistakes within the Xaml either.

Comment: Just to verify, I have just added the <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Criteria}" /> to the RadDocumentPane (under the grid) and it displays correctly. Has to be something to do with the Telerik Docking panels.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't make sense. Where does _"cannot find property on SearchCriteriaViewModel"_  come from? When the `DataContext` is the `SearchCriteriaViewModel` and this is riight then how can those bindings fail? So if you add the conrtols directly to the pane and it is still empty then there must be some error source I can't see.

Comment: It's strange that you can't eevn add content directly.

Comment: "cannot find property on SearchCriteriaViewModel" is shown in the VS Output window; it is looking to bind properties that exist on the SearchCriteria object, not the SearchCriteriaViewModel that owns it - irrespective of my binding the DataContext of the parent.

Comment: When you add content directly that what do you see - nothing or just empty controls because the bindings fail?

Comment: Does not get that far as complains about 2 way bindings. Have found some interesting articles on Telerik site though that basically rule out any kind of binding with the docking!

Comment: You can try out [AvalonDock](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/AvalonDock) from Xceed. I think it's free as standalone and part of the Xceed Toolkit. I used it before and at least it doesn't mess up with the bindings and is also easy to customize. I think the visual appearance is better. Almost like Visual Studio.

Comment: Anyway, good luck.